# Dropbox on ubuntu not sync-uploading although sync-downloading works and other machines work normally

Tags: sync, dropbox

I have been using Dropbox across Mac, Windows, Ubuntu for a few years, but recently the syncing of file changes I make on Ubuntu has stopped working.  However, the syncing of file changes on the other machines continues as normal, and changes I make on the other machines do get synced onto the Ubuntu machine.  So it's just the changes that I make on Ubuntu that don't seem to be uploaded to the other machines.

After I make changes to a Dropbox file locally on Ubuntu, if  I open the web interface to Dropbox on my ubuntu machine, it seems to be aware of only the older versions of the file before I started my current session of file changes.  If I drop the newer  versions of the file created on Ubuntu into the web page, then it uploads and then all the  machines see my changes. So the Ubuntu machine is really changing the files locally but unlike the other machines where local changes are automatically synced, on the Ubuntu machine this no longer happens.

I haven't done anything to the Ubuntu system other than the normal stream of automatic ubuntu system updates .

This "failure to sync" is  a persistent condition, continuing across many days of system power offs and restarts (and further automatic system updates).  I haven't noticed any other unusual behavior or breakage for the other features I use on the machine.

Do I need to do a reinstall?  Or is there some other way to clear this up?

Thanks.